# How to plot a bar graph in R

Tags: r

```
       Salary

Matt    5000
Jon      6000
Jay      8000
Noman    4000
Roy      6000
```

How do I create a bar graph from this in R, I don't have column name for the names (is there any way to create a bar graph in R with names on the X axis and Salary on Y axis?

Comment: Check out this link: http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/qualitative-data/bar-graph

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. As this appears to be an absolute beginners question I advise to become as comfortable with the `plot` function as possible. Thus:

```
id <- c("Matt", "Jon", "Jay", "Noman", "Roy")
salary <- c(5000, 6000, 8000, 4000, 6000)

plot(salary, type="h", xaxt="n")
axis(1, 1:length(id), labels=id)
```

This is perfectly fine, but may not be what you expect when you think of a barplot. For a more conventional form of barplot use

```
barplot(salary, names.arg=id)
```

A number of people prefer doing graphics with the ggplot2 package:

```
d <- data.frame(id=id, salary=salary)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x=id, y=salary)) + geom_col()
```